# ClassCastException in casting DTMManagerDefault into DTMManager during maven jaxb codegen

Tags: java, maven-2, classcastexception, jaxb2

I'm having a strange problem when trying to run a maven build that uses the jaxb2 plugin to do JAXB codegen (see stacktrace below). The best that I can figure is that there's some implementation of DTMManager that's being class loaded from a different JAR than the one in xalan-2.7.1; however, I have verified that the classpath that is used for running the jaxb:generate goal only has the one xalan-2.7.1.jar that contains a DTMManager or a DTMManagerDefault - so I have no clue what else might be getting in the way.

One final data point: our build specifies a 'snapshot' profile, which really only serves to also JAR up the sources (using maven-source-plugin) and publish them as artifacts. The failure scenario I described above *only* occurs when this profile is specified in addition to the default.

I'm using Maven 2.2.1 running on Sun's 64-bit JDK 1.6.0_21 on Linux x64 (Fedora 13) - see below the stacktrace for the 'mvn -v' info.

Any ideas on what the problem may be and/or how to go about debugging it? This has been causing me grief for the past few days and it's now blocking progress :(

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager
    at org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager.newInstance(DTMManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.<init>(XPathContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:207)
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:281)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:224)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:289)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:134)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:96)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.transform(DOMForest.java:448)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:342)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:374)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:113)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.XJC2Mojo.runXJC(XJC2Mojo.java:1119)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.XJC2Mojo.execute(XJC2Mojo.java:720)
...
```

mvn -v:

```
# mvn -v
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 14:16:01-0500)
Java version: 1.6.0_21
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.33.3-85.fc13.x86_64" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to search for all dependencies on Xalan and xercesImpl in the classpath . These dependencies should be excluded.

**Updated**

I found an answer like this - see http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@qpid.apache.org/msg07295.html

```
Had a look at this closely and figured it was due to a classpath class
due to Sun bundling an older version of Xalan jar.
I have disabled this test until we come up with a decent solution.

Rajith
```

Comment: Hello, can you explain how can I do this? I have the same problem with Debian+Jboss and can't fix it on Linux, but works fine on Windows/Mac. Thanks.

Comment: Run  {mvn dependency:tree > dependencies.txt} then add exclude to your dependencies for the jars that should be excluded.

Answer (score 4):

To exclude the `xalan` and `xercesImpl` dependencies in Maven:

```
    <dependency> <!-- ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.dom.DOMXPath -->
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>maven-findbugs-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>maven-cobertura-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault -> org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager -->
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

See also https://community.jboss.org/wiki/FreeMarkerAndJBossAS7 .

Answer (score 0):

For me setting following JVM property worked.

```
-Dorg.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager=org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault
```